# Missing generated types in java_first_jaxws sample of cxf

Tags: soap, cxf

In the `java_first_jaxws` sample I do not see generated types like `SayHi.java` and `SayHiResponse.java`. Why not? How can serialize/deserialize work when they are not there?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example, especially the interface [HelloWorld](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_jaxws/src/main/java/demo/hw/server/HelloWorld.java):

```
String sayHi(String text);
String sayHiToUser(User user);
```

SayHi is an operation. Operation are defined by the methods in the interface. Also, this example is Bottom-Up, not Top-Down, which means there is no code generated.